# How to run emacs (or aquamacs, if possible :-) ) in a window that plays nice with tiling window manager yabai?

Tags: osx, aquamacs

I've just installed the tiling window manager yabai, but soon found that emacs/aquamacs windows don't tile like terminal or windows for most apps.

Time was, emacs ran in a terminal window. Awkward, I know after you've gotten used to the newer, GUI version. It would be best if emacs/aquamacs GUI window were able to be tiled, but a terminal version of emacs would definitely tile.

I don't want to be driven into the arms of nvim...

Comment: I have used Emacs with several different window managers (on Linux though) and never had this kind of problem. It looks like it is a window manager issue, not an Emacs one.

Comment: Define "play nice". Describe what the problem is. Ask a specific question. Thx.

Comment: By 'play nice' I mean Aquamacs frames to act like Terminal windows, that is, tile instead of disappearing. Emacs, however, seems to agree to be tiled...

Comment: Problem solved: I discovered the -nw flag to have emacs run in a terminal window